# How to parse definition lists ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, 7

I want to write definition lists with ,  and  tags with drupal commons 3 in CKEditor. I am writing code directly (while I am in source mode) then switch to WYSIWYG and go back to source. CKEditor change this tags to paragraphs.

How to not transform definitions tags (dl, dt, dd) ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue myself.

The way I got around it was to add them to the Extra Allowed Content in the profile edit form.

[image: screencap of the Advanced Content Filter section of the form]

You'll also be pleased to note that while the definition list tags are being presented as p tags they are still stored as the original tags in the db. You won't need to rebuild your definition list.